# Should a new type be created though it only wraps a single field?

Tags: java, object-oriented-design

Say I have an interface `Species` that's defined as

```
public interface Species {

    String getId();

    String getDescription();
}
```

The question is simply this: Should I create different classes to represent these two fields, even though it does not add additional clarity to the code? For example

```
public interface SpeciesIdentifier {

    String getValue();
}

public interface SpeciesDescription {

    String getValue();
}

public interface Species {

    SpeciesIdentifier getId();

    SpeciesDescription getDescription();
}
```

The primary use of the `Species` class is as a DTO.

Comment: Interfaces should be designed for the clients of the contract.  Would you have clients that would only use one of these fields?

Comment: `Species.getId` should return an implementation of the interface `SpeciesIdentifier`? Please make sure your code compiles.

Answer (score 2):

Creating interfaces for single values may make sense if you want to create a very robust API, which should endure even if requirements change, or if you are not sure how the values will be implemented (will id be a String or int? Will description be simple String, or an object with more structured data, such as group, textual note, comments).

Generally, it is better to keep things simple if you don't anticipate many changes or you can afford to change also all clients.

Beware that if you pass the values between multiple modules or even through remote invocation, not only interfaces must be in classpath on both sides, but also their implementations.

Comment: In addition to resist to changes, classes/interfaces with a single value may be used to get a stronger type safety in the program: "No, this is not a simple string, this is actually a species id". It makes easier the understanding of parameters: "This method is waiting for a species id, not a simple string" and therefore limits the risk to misuse a method. It also makes sense when your programming style involves type based behaviour (for instance, with pattern matching).